# "You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core" and/or "rxjs". This is an error. " when deploying MEAN-app to Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, deployment, mean

I want to deploy my MEAN-stack application using Heroku. I have followed [this tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDYhwfi7VU0) mostly to build my app. But when I start deployment by pushing to GIT, it gives me this error during the build process:

```
meanstacknieuw@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_837e48e6_
   > cd client && ng build --aot --prod
   
   You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core" and/or "rxjs". This is an error.
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 2
   npm ERR! meanstacknieuw@1.0.0 postinstall: `cd client && ng build --aot --prod`
   npm ERR! Exit status 2
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the meanstacknieuw@1.0.0 postinstall script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

this is my package.json (of the server side):

```
{
  "name": "meanstacknieuw",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "refreshing",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.3",
    "npm": "6.11.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && ng build --aot --prod",
    "postinstall": "cd client && ng build --aot --prod"
  },
   "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/y0u-s/vf-app.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "MEAN",
    "stack",
    "angular",
    "2",
   "application"
   ],
  "author": "Youssef",
   "license": "ISC",
   "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/y0u-s/latest-mean-stack-app/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/y0u-s/latest-mean-stack-app#readme",
  "dependencies": {
   "@angular/cli": "^8.3.20",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
   "angular2-flash-messages": "^3.0.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.4",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
 "cors": "^2.8.5",
"express": "^4.16.4",
"file-extension": "^4.0.5",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"multer": "^1.4.2",
"node-localstorage": "^2.1.4",
"nodemailer": "^6.4.1",
"simple-odata-server": "^1.1.1",
"typescript": "~3.2.2"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.20"
 }
}
```

Whats going wrong? Please let me know i you need more context.

EDIT:

```
       -----> Restoring cache
      Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of 
  node, npm, yarn or stack
   Module installation may take longer for this build
   
   -----> Installing dependencies
   Installing node modules
   npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and 
package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock 
file with `npm install` before continuing.
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Missing: @angular/rxjs@^8.2.14
   npm ERR! Missing: @angular/core@^8.2.14
   npm ERR! Missing: @angular/common@^8.2.14
   npm ERR! Missing: @angular/platform-browser@^8.2.14
   npm ERR!
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if you already have the `node_modules` directory under your project directory? If so, remove the directory and reinstall `npm install`.

And I noticed you don't have `@angular/core` and `rxjs` in `package.json`. Please add them by doing `npm install @angular/core rxjs --save`. Also you should have `@angular/common, @angular/platform-browser`, too.

Comment: do i have to install these in the client folder?

Comment: yes, in the directory where the package.json exists.

Comment: i have package.json in both my server and client folder so im a bit confused about that

Comment: then do it under the client folder.

Comment: can you please look at his package.json file? https://github.com/gugui3z24/MEAN-Stack-With-Angular-2-Tutorial/blob/master/package.json

Comment: he also doesnt have those @angular/core etc there ..

Comment: You should check `https://github.com/gugui3z24/MEAN-Stack-With-Angular-2-Tutorial/blob/master/client/package.json`. There are all dependencies for bootstrapping angular project. Just renew the `npm install` after deleting `/client/node_modules` directory.

Comment: i have added those lines to my package.json , please see my edited post for the error message i get now

Answer (score 0):

You don't have all the required dependencies to run an Angular project. Typical dependencies are as follows (you may need different versions):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^10.1.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.1.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "csstype": "^2.5.8",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0"
  },
```